# Restricting what data gets uploaded to QGISCloud

Tags: qgis, qgis-cloud

I have set up a free account on QGISCloud and installed the Cloud plugin but I am having problems restricting the data that gets uploaded.

I have four (plus a background) layers open in QGIS but when I try and upload data using the plugin it lists a fifth layer which I had deleted from the project.  Unfortunately that layer is full of "non public" information.  I first tried saving the project and restarting QGIS in case it was some how lingering in memory but I had the same result.

Any clues as to what is going on here?

[image: scree shot of the upload form]

The selected layer (wp_master) is not referenced by this project and, so far as I can tell should not be uploaded.

Some of the data in wp_master is potentially sensitive and I definitely do not have authority to upload this data anywhere remotely public.

QGIS 2.18.9 running on a Mac ( High Sierra )

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it for a while I came to the conclusion that there had to be lingering evidence of the deleted layers in the project file and sure enough when I looked I found several references to the PostGIS table in question which had not been deleted when the layers that referenced it were.

The solution was to open a new project and build everything from scratch.